# Activity, Service binding

Tags: android, service

Can an Activity be bound to two different Services at the same time or do I have to unbind one Service before binding to the other one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry, Mark is right - you shouldn't have any problems.

Actual excerpt from my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    bindService(Intents.PRIMARY_MANAGER_INTENT, mPrimManagerConn,
                    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    bindService(Intents.SECONDARY_MANAGER_INTENT, mSecManagerConn,
                    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but an `Activity` should be able to bind to two `Services`, so long as each binding uses a separate `ServiceConnection` object.